# Multisim solution vs hand calculation

Tags: circuits

I am presented with the circuit shown in the figure below.
[image]

The hand calculations are as follows:
[image]

When I build the circuit in Multisim as shown in the image below:
[image]

My calculations are not matching up with the simulation results. Im pretty confident in my hand calculations. It is the simulation I am not sure about, but I could be wrong. Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Comment: In the multi sim model, the input to the cccs is shorting the 80 ohm resistor.

Comment: Im not sure exactly how to correct that.

Comment: Put the control port of the cccs in series with the resistor instead of in parallel.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I would like to show the snapshot of the corrected version, should I add that as an edit to my original post?

Comment: You could post an answer and include it there.

Answer (score 1):

As The Photon suggested in his comment earlier, I was shorting out the CCCS with the 80 Ohm resistor. Below is the diagram that shows the 80 Ohm Resistor connected in series with the CCCS instead of in parallel.
[image]